# WooCommerce Admin Product Search by SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have been searching around looking for a way to incorporate this without installing another plugin that does way more than I need.

Lets say our product SKUs are structured in a way that provide the vendor number, then a dash (-), and then the product id. So our SKUs look like this 469-852369 (vendor-product). The vendor ID can be anywhere from 1 to 5 digits and the product ID can be anywhere from 1 to 10 digits. We want to be able to search for the product without having to add the dash (-). So for 469-852369 I want to be able to just type out 469852369 and the product appears.

I know there are a LOT of plugins out there that will do this but I don't want to add a plugin just to accomplish this one issue. Any help and guidance on how to accomplish this via PHP would help.

Answer (score 5):

You can set your custom query to search result. while searching normally with "469852369" you can append "-" after 3 digits like "469-852369" and then pass it into WordPress query to get results.

```
function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {

  global $wpdb;

  $sku = implode("-", str_split($sku, 3));

  $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

  if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );

  // YOUR CODE

  return null;

}
```

Hope this will helpful for you somehow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could replace the SQL-query in Ahmed Ginani's answer with this one and get what you want:

```
SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (REPLACE(meta_value, '-', '')) = '%s' AND meta_key='_sku';
```

Answer (score -2):

use the code:

```
function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );
  if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );
  return null;
}
```